# Send Email in CakePHP afterSave

Tags: email, cakephp

I'm trying to create an email component/model that will add an email to the database (with certain fields like, to, from, subject, message, created, modified, etc).

AFTER the data has been sucessfully saved (which it currently does), I'd like to actually send the message.

I figure this would be easiest with an afterSave() function, but I cannot get the email to send.

Here is some relevant code:

Email Model

```
<?php
class Email extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Email';

    var $displayField = 'subject';

        function afterSave() {

            $this->Email->to = $this->data['Email']['email'];
            $this->Email->subject = $this->data['Email']['subject'];
            $this->Email->replyTo = $this->data['Email']['email'];
            $this->Email->from = 'Private Message <' . $this->data['Email']['email'] . '>';
            //$this->Email->template = 'simple_message';
            $this->Email->send($this->data['Email']['email_text']);

        }
}
```

add.ctp for email

```
<div class="universities form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Email');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Add Email'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('subject');
        echo $this->Form->input('email_text');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('email', array('value' => $this->params['named']['contact_email']));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('user_from', array('value' => $this->Session->read('User.id')));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('created', array('value' => date("Y-m-d")));
        echo $this->Form->hidden('modified', array('value' => date("Y-m-d")));

    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

Controller save code:

```
    function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Email->create();
//                        pr($this->data);
//                        die;
            if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email has been saved', true));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
    }
```

Error I am getting on trying to send:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::send() in /Users/[USER]/Sites/example_app/app/models/email.php on line 14
```

New Controller Code:

```
function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Email->create();
//                        pr($this->data);
//                        die;
            if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email has been saved', true));

                                function _sendMail() {
                                    $this->Email->to = $this->data['Email']['email'];
                                    $this->Email->subject = $this->data['Email']['subject'];
                                    $this->Email->replyTo = $this->data['Email']['email'];
                                    $this->Email->from = 'Private Message <' . $this->data['Email']['email'] . '>';
                                    $this->Email->sendAs = 'text'; //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
                                    $email->send();
                                }

                                $this->_sendMail();

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

components are meant to be used in a controller, not the model - so the cleanest way is to send the mail from controller when $this->Model->save() returns true.

Because you did name your Model "Email", i dont think you can use the component "Email" the standard way and need to load it manually:

In the controller (function add())

```
if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
    // save was successfull

    App::import('Component', 'Email');
    $email = new EmailComponent();
    $email->startup($this);

    $email->from='joe@example.com';
    $email->to = $this->data['Email']['email'];
    $email->subject = $this->data['Email']['subject'];
    $email->replyTo = $this->data['Email']['email'];
    $email->from = 'Private Message <' . $this->data['Email']['email'] . '>';
    $email->sendAs = 'text'; //Send as 'html', 'text' or 'both' (default is 'text')
    $email->send();


    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email has been saved', true));
}
```

Nevertheless it is possible to send mails from the model, see the second answer of this (duplicate) thread:
[How do I use the email component from a model in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312846/how-do-i-use-the-email-component-from-a-model-in-cakephp)

Comment: If I were to use this same code in my afterSave in my controller, would it work, or would I need to modify other things?

Comment: hmm ... its not that easy, because your model is named "Email" too - can you post the part of your controller where you save the data into the model?

Comment: Ok I've moved it to the controller, and followed the instructions from that link in the answer above and get the error message I just added tot he bottom of the big text there.

Comment: added new controller code that i'm attempting, thanks a ton for the help by the way.  truly appreciated.

Comment: So I should keep the code in my model and insert your code above it?  Sorry, not everyone is as experienced and understands CakePHP as others... thanks again for the help.

Comment: ok - i rewrote the anser, yes keep it in the controller (see above)

Comment: Thanks, still getting the undefined class send() though... I loaded the component...

Comment: Is it possible that in your model the afterSave() Method with $this-Email->send() is still present?

Comment: It was, got rid of that, says the email saved but it didn't send.  Do I need to set up smtp settings somewhere?

Comment: if you are sending from your local machine, yes i would recommend a smtp server - but i think the script itself works so far if there are no errors returned...

Comment: Tried from a dev server that has smtp setup, email saves to DB but won't actually send email.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, couldn't get it working somehow... must be screwing something up since all this data is dynamic.

Comment: Hi, you can avoid the dynamics-factor if you hardcode an email adress, subject and body (have you set a bodytext to send()?) instead of using the form variables. But as email sending from script is a very complex topic - please close this question and look further on the topic why emails don't get through eg. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820079/safe-way-to-send-mail-via-php-to-many-users

Comment: Pretty much used this, had to modify a bit and ended up moving it to app_controller but works great.  Thanks!